# Selenium 2.42.2 is not working to invoke .exe like for AutoIt

Tags: java, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, testng, autoit

I want to upload a photo by selenium webdriver.
I used following environment:

```
[Selenium 2.42.2][1]
TestNg,
Firefox 26to 30,
[AutoIt][2]
```

Here is `Test.java` code

```
  driver.findElement(By.id("photo")).click();

  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Z://browseExample.exe");
```

But selenium does not run the line to execute automatically.
If I manually clicks on `browseExample.exe` then it writes the desired path in `browse` textbox and clicks on open.

I noticed that, with selenium jar like 2.39, 2,38 it works fine.

But with those jars, my application's one locator of password field is not working.
When password is entered it displays in plain text and even clicking on submit button, it doesn't accept that password.

Here is the html of `password` field

```
<div class="formbox">
<input type="password" value="Password" onclick="this.value == 'Password' ? this.value = '' : this.value;" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="javascript:return ShowDefaultText();" maxlength="255" title="Please enter password" name="textBoxPassword" tabindex="2" id="textBoxPassword" style="display: none;">
<input value="Password" onclick="this.value == 'Password' ? this.value = '' : this.value;" onfocus="javascript:return HideDefaultText();" maxlength="255" title="Please enter password" tabindex="2" name="textBoxPasswordRegular" class="logintext" id="textBoxPasswordRegular" style="display: block;">
</div>
```

Here is AutoIT code of `browseExample.exe`

```
; Wait 10 seconds for the Upload window to appear

  WinWait("[CLASS:#32770]","",10)

; Set input focus to the edit control of Upload window using the handle returned by WinWait

  ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")

  Sleep(2000)

; Set the File name text on the Edit field

  ControlSetText("File Upload", "", "Edit1", "Z:\snipett.txt")

  Sleep(2000)

; Click on the Open button

  ControlClick("File Upload", "","Button1");
```

Comment: Try to change // to \\ (Z:\\browseExample.exe)

Comment: I already tried it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this will help you, but i think you don't necessary to use autoit to interact with dialog. I don't know java, but in C# there are a lot of libs to get any window and has possibility to interact with any element in app (e.g. [UIAutomation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx)). You can use winapi to get browse For file dialog and find textBox in it. Or you can use .net library for same purposes, i think there are a lot of articles how to use .net library in java (java .net interop).

Comment: I searched but couldnot find anything helpful

Answer (score 0):

Open Dialog is not a top level window, its a child window.
In order for Autoit to detect child windows you need to set:

```
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also
```

Allows the window search routines to search child windows as well as top-level windows.
0 = Only search top-level windows (default)
1 = Search top-level and child windows

Also its smart to add **#RequireAdmin** to the top of your Autoit script. That can solve a permission elevation problems.

About password field,
In your html you have some onclick code that will do certain processing of the password, like eg. changing the type of the input (this is why you see plain text.)
Invoke click and focus events on the input field before or/and after setting the value.

Comment: I tried with `code` Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ; `code` but it couldn't work on selenium 2.42.2. Without using that code, my code of autoit is also working fine with selenium 2.39 etc

Comment: regarding that password field, its behavior is when there is no focus on password control, "Password" remains displayed to user but as he clicks, it disappears and in encrypted form user's input is taken.......But when I tried to locate that element it worked fine with selenium 2.42.2 but in lower versions, either input is not sent in text box or its displayed as a plain text. I used css locator : "#textBoxPassword" or "textBoxPasswordRegular".

Comment: I used code for login as  getPassWord().click();getPassWord2().sendkeys("yourPassword"); where public static final String password = "#textBoxPasswordRegular";
 public static final String password2 = "#textBoxPassword"; so it worked for login functionality for selenium 2.39 and my code of file upload also worked for that. However selenium 2.42.2 has problem with calling an exe.

Comment: So my suggestion to click before sending is working?
Answer edited. Added a possible fix for your first problem.

Comment: See adding of click I also tried and you said that also , but here it requires click on different locator , generally we opt for same locator